# Yo generator subgenerator not available. When doing an NPM install it doesn't pull all the code down

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I'm working on creating an Yo generator to generate hapijs modules. I've published this to NPM and when I create a new project and do an `npm install generator-hapijs`, it doesn't pull all the code down into my `node_modules/generator-hapijs` directory and therefore my subgenerator is not available when doing a `yo --help`. Why not and how can I fix this?

Here's my code: https://github.com/toymachiner62/generator-hapijs

Here's what's available in my node_modules/generator-hapijs folder when installing this package in a new project:

```
-/project
--/node_modules
---/generator-hapijs
----/app
----/node_modules
----package.json
----README.md
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It had nothing to do with yeoman and yo, but rather had to do with the fact that I had a `files` array in my package.json and it only contained `app` so when installing it only installed files from the `/app` folder.

I just removed the `files` array from my `package.json` file.